# Unity3D: Entering a trigger disables a few bools for no reason

Tags: unity, c#, boolean

I'm trying to make it so when an object enters a collider with the tag "Down" a single boolean turns false, but the problem is that more than one booleans(*canGoUp, canGoLeft, canGoRight*) are turning false for no reason, here's my code.

```
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider col)
    {
        if(col.gameObject.tag == "Up")
        {
            canGoUp = false;
        }
        if (col.gameObject.tag == "Down")
        {
            canGoDown = false;
        }
        if (col.gameObject.tag == "Left")
        {
            canGoLeft = false;
        }
        if (col.gameObject.tag == "Right")
        {
            canGoRight = false;
        }

    }

    void OnTriggerExit(Collider col)
    {
        if (col.gameObject.tag == "Up")
        {
            canGoUp = true;
        }
        if (col.gameObject.tag == "Down")
        {
            canGoDown = true;
        }
        if (col.gameObject.tag == "Left")
        {
            canGoLeft = true;
        }
        if (col.gameObject.tag == "Right")
        {
            canGoRight = true;
        }
    }
```

The other parts of the script work well, but not the "Down" one, here are two objects compared to each other:

[image]
[image]

Comment: There is nothing to say with this limited information given. But, as it seems to me problem is not in the code, but in your scene setup.

Comment: It's not limited information, it's all there is to it. I added two images of two gameobject properties, the "Up" one works but the "Down" one doesn't. It makes no sense to me

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there were a few more objects with those tags which were colliding with the object and that's why this "bug" appeared. Deleted those objects and fixed it.